# Bug in the daily rep limit code?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Earlier today I downvoted an answer, then after the OP had edited it I retracted my downvote. In between I had hit the daily rep limit of 215 (including one accept) and now after retracting my downvote I find I have 216 rep for the day.

Obviously the determined gamer's strategy should be to make lots of downvotes early in the day then retract them all at the end of the day :-)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13851/209806

Comment: While this seems like unwanted behaviour, recall that you can only retract votes after such a long time if the post has been edited, so the gamer will either have to edit a lot or have a lot of luck ;)

Comment: @ACuriousMind I wonder if personally editing it will make a difference or not ;)

Comment: Are you saying you gain reputation by retracting downvotes? It just your own reputation point you get back, right?

Comment: @Bernhard: see my comment to tgp2114's answer

Comment: @JohnRennie I was a bit confused by your formulation. So you went from x-1 to x+215. Then retracted the downvote to get x+216. I read it as you went to x-1+215.

Comment: John, since meta posts are really meant for generic site policies and information, I think you can make a much better case if you also incorporate @Danu's pointer and accordingly _edit_ the post!

Comment: @TheDarkSide: I'm not sure I follow your meaning.

Comment: What I meant was, since as ACuriousMind had pointed out, editing bit is a crucial freak factor here. So, from the point of view of gaming, things would be easier, if the gamer had 2k+ already, so that editing is not a concern anymore.

Comment: @TheDarkSide: ah, you confused me by referring to *Danu's pointer*. I don't plan to edit the post because it isn't meant to be a gamer's guide. I posted only because I was amused at having (accidentally) gamed the system and gained a whole one rep point :-)